# How to patch managed configuration per device for any app like Gmail

Tags: android, gmail, exchange-server, android-management-api

I am using Android Management API to provision and patch devices in the enterprise. I can see that there is an API to patch the policy with managed configuration. But I have a requirement to patch each device uniquely. I want to patch the Gmail app with a unique exchange id for each device.
I have not been able to find a way to do this with android management API. Is there a way to do it.
Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a policy per device containing your exchange ID and apply that policy for one device. You have to manage all this in your own code.
Answer from Google support - https://support.google.com/work/android/thread/117966396/how-to-push-exchange-id-managed-configuration-to-gmail-though-android-management-api?hl=en&msgid=117966396